# Erro - Conectar com Mysql com PDO

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando conectar em um Banco Mysql Remotamente, através do PDO + PHP. O Banco Mysql é gerenciado por uma equipe, não tenho acesso a ela. O Banco foi criado e as tabelas também. Foi dada as devidas permissões ao banco pelo meu usuário. Porem, quando tento fazer a conexão a ele via PHP + PDO gera o erro abaixo:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'xxx:3306' (2)' in xxx:8 Stack trace: #0 xxx(8): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=a1-o...', 'user', 'senha') #1 xxx: db_connect() #2 {main} thrown in xxx on line 8
```

Deixamos um tcpdump rodando no ambiente do Mysql e quando fazemos a tentativa de conexão com o banco via PHP, não chega pacote lá. Mas fecha telnet na porta 3306.

Dados de conexão com o Mysql

```
define('DB_HOST', 'xxx:3306');
define('DB_USER', 'xxx');
define('DB_PASS', 'xxxx');
define('DB_NAME', 'xxx');

    <?php

/**
 * Conecta com o MySQL usando PDO
 */
function db_connect()
{
    $PDO = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS);

    return $PDO;
}



?>
```

Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Comment: 1) A porta 3306 e default você pode omitir ela.
2) DSN é no seguinte formato "mysql:host=xxxx;port=3306;dbname=xxx", você não adicionou ";port="

Comment: @anderson, acabei de testar com sua sugestão/orientação e o mesmo erro ocorreu: Can't connect to MySQL server . Localhost funciona, porem setando um mysql remoto dá este erro. Preciso forçar o php enchergar um mysql remoto? Deixei um tcpdump rodando para o destino e não sai nenhum pacote pra lá.

Comment: as messagem de erro são diferentes: "QLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host" outra "Can't connect to MySQL server", você pode estar com restrição de "host name", tenta realizar procedimento abaixo para testar sua permissão de host name.